# PHP and MySQL search across lots of columns

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, lucene, sphinx

I need a way to search through 50+ columns, both varchar and int, in a specific table.  I've seen people recommend Lucene and Sphinx, but I have no clue how to go about using those and MySQL's Full-Text won't allow me to combine more than 16 columns or both varchar and int columns.

Answer (score 2):

If your table doesn't get updated a lot, or some time lag before changes are reflected in search is acceptable, perhaps you could make a periodically-regenerated derived table that combines all of your columns in a `LONGTEXT` and has a fulltext index on that.

Comment: the problem is that there are roughly 65,000 rows at this point with about 500 being added weekly.

Comment: If the 500 are in a batch, rather than at random, it'd be easy to regenerate the derived table after the batch.  Assuming the inserts come at random times, though, 500 a week is still only a little more than one an hour on average.  You could probably run an every-minute cron job that would regenerate the derived table if any changes had been made and not feel any particular pain.

Comment: +1 for a denormalised table with MySQL FULLTEXT indexes.

I'd look at sphinx as a first option though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider pivoting your table and chopping it up a bit. Take all your varchar columns and store the data in one table "Search_Strings"; do the same for the int columns:

original table

```
id
always_field1
always_field2
varstring1
...
varstringx
int1
...
inty
```

new main_table (same number of rows as original table, but very few columns)

```
id
always_field1
always_field2
```

Search_Strings (

```
id (FK to main_table)
old_column_name
string_value
```

Search_Ints

```
id (FK to main_table)
old_column_name
int_value
```

With this setup, you need a fulltext index only on string_value.  Sorry I can't suggest anything with Sphinx or Lucene as I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: To index this strings table using Sphinx, you just need to make sure the "strings" table has a unique id key (think sequences).  cf:  http://www.postneo.com/2009/02/06/sphinx-search-with-postgresql